# Tracking downloaded file from specific website

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a windows service application which can tracking file changes in a folder.Here, I used FileSystemWatcher and it works properly. Now, I am trying to detect/tracking a file which download from a specific website. Anyone can help me?